# SQL error: near ""threatAgent_id"": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

i am trying to run the following query to make a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "attack" (
      "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
      "name" VARCHAR , 
      "description" TEXT check(typeof("description") = 'text') , 
      "probability" DOUBLE ,

      "asset_id" INTEGER  ,
      FOREIGN KEY ( "asset_id") REFERENCES  asset(id)   ,

      "threatAgent_id" INTEGER  ,
      FOREIGN KEY ( "threatAgent_id") REFERENCES  threatAgent(id) ,

      "vulnerability_id"  INTEGER  ,
      FOREIGN KEY ( "vulnerability_id") REFERENCES  vulnerability(id)

 ) ;
```

but it complains that

```
 error: near ""threatAgent_id"": syntax error
```

i have made the `threatAgent` using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE "threatAgent" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "means" TEXT check(typeof("means") = 'text') , "motivation" VARCHAR, "capabilities" VARCHAR, "opportunities" VARCHAR)
```

So, **why it is complaining?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not like interlacing column definitions with constraint definitions.  So when it gets to the first constraint it thinks there won't be any more columns.

Move all the constraint definitions to the bottom to resolve.

```
CREATE TABLE "attack" (
      "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
      "name" VARCHAR , 
      "description" TEXT check(typeof("description") = 'text') , 
      "probability" DOUBLE ,
      "asset_id" INTEGER , 
      "threatAgent_id" INTEGER  ,
      "vulnerability_id"  INTEGER  ,

      FOREIGN KEY ( "asset_id") REFERENCES  asset(id)   ,
      FOREIGN KEY ( "threatAgent_id") REFERENCES  threatAgent(id) ,
      FOREIGN KEY ( "vulnerability_id") REFERENCES  vulnerability(id)

 ) ;
```